# Vue 3 + Typescript + JSX and img loading={"lazy"} give error: Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'ElementAttrs<ImgHTMLAttributes>'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

```
Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'ElementAttrs<ImgHTMLAttributes>'
```

- vue: ^3.0.0
- @vue/babel-plugin-jsx: ^1.0.3
- typescript: ^3.9.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your `main.ts` after imports this code:

```
// Fix: Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'ElementAttrs<ImgHTMLAttributes>'
declare module "@vue/runtime-dom" {
    interface ImgHTMLAttributes extends HTMLAttributes {
        loading?: "lazy" | "eager" | "auto";
    }
}
```